# Get the left hand class of static method invocation?

Tags: java, generics

Sometimes it is useful to get the type name from static invoke, see this example:

```
class Base {
    private static void funImpl(Class<? extends Base> type) {
        ...
    }
    public static void fun() {
        fun(Base.class);
    }
}

class User extends Base {
    public static void fun() {
        fun(User.class);
    }
}
```

Here `fun()` is declared for each subclass. So, can I write something like this?

```
class Base {
     private static void funImpl(Class<? extends Base> type) {
         ...
     }
     public static void fun() {
         Class<?> leftHandClass = System.getLeftHandClass(); // Error: d'oh...
         funImpl(leftHandClass);
     }
}

class User extends Base {
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that what you are trying to achieve with static methods is precisely what object-oriented-programming (object instances with non-static methods) was invented for.

Comment: 看不动.  The answer is probably not.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: what is getLeftHandClass() ? Unfortunately, I have never heard of the API before and neither can I locate it on the net... you can't get child class's name / class object in a static method if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed. Rather than the superclass having to be "told" what subclass is using it, you do it the other way around and declare abstract methods in the superclass for the subclasses to implement. That way, instead of having one big class that has a bunch of case statements to handle each of its subclasses, the code specific to each subclass goes in the subclass.

If your problem is that you want your subclass instances to be singletons (i.e. so as to use a static method), consider using an enumeration. So rather than calling a static method on a class, you call an instance method on the enumeration constant: SQUARE.fun() etc.

```
enum Foo {
    SQUARE {
        public String getColor() {
            return "RED";
        }
    },
    CIRCLE {
        public String getColor() {
            return "GREEN";
        }
    },
    TRIANGLE {
        public String getColor() {
            return "BLUE";
        }
    };
    public abstract String getColor();

    public void fun() {
        System.out.println("I am a " + name() + " and my color is " + getColor());
    }
}
```